# Apk Expansion Files - Application Licensing - Developer account - NOT_LICENSED response

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the APK Expansion Files extension for Android.
I have uploaded the APK to the server along with the extension files. If the application
was previously published i get a response from the server saying NOT_LICENSED:
The code I use is:

```
APKExpansionPolicy aep = new APKExpansionPolicy(mContext,
                new AESObfuscator(getSALT(), mContext.getPackageName(), deviceId));
aep.resetPolicy();
LicenseChecker checker = new LicenseChecker(mContext, aep,
                getPublicKey();
checker.checkAccess(new LicenseCheckerCallback() {   
            @Override
            public void allow(int reason) { 
            @Override
            public void dontAllow(int reason) {
                try
                {
                    switch (reason) {
                        case Policy.NOT_LICENSED:
mNotification.onDownloadStateChanged(IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED_UNLICENSED);
                            break;
                        case Policy.RETRY:
mNotification.onDownloadStateChanged(IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED_FETCHING_URL);
                            break;
                    }
                } finally {
                    setServiceRunning(false);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
                try {
mNotification.onDownloadStateChanged(IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED_FETCHING_URL);
                } finally {
                    setServiceRunning(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

So if the application wasn't previously published the Allow method is called. If the application was previously published and now it isn't the dontAllow method is called.

I have tried:

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html#test-response
   Here it says that if you use a developer or test account on your
   test device you can set a specific response, I use LICENSED as
   response and still get NOT_LINCESED.
2. Resetting the phone, clearing google play store cache, application
   data.
3. Changing the versioncode number in different combinations still doesn't work.

**Edit:**
In case someone else was facing this problem I received an mail from the google support team

> We are aware that newly created accounts for testing in-app billing
>   and Google licensing server (LVL) return errors, and are working on
>   resolving this problem. Please stay tuned. In the meantime, you can
>   use any accounts created prior to August 1st, 2012, for testing.
>   So it seems to be a problem with their server, if I use the main developer thread 
>   everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried signing the application with the release key that you also have used for publishing the application?

Just as with in-app-billing this can only be tested when you sign your app with the correct release key. Otherwise Google can't verify that the requests are coming from the correct app.

Comment: Yes. I have tried that. Anyway the problem solved itself it was actually a related to their servers. Now it is working seamlessly.